# PAT table .sec to .py conversion

Tags: python

In Digital Television there are some tables used for signaling. This tables can be defined in .py files, to later be converted to .sec and finally to .ts, so they can be muxed. To accomplish this, the next code is used:

```
out = open("./pat.sec", "wb")
out.write(pat.pack())
out.close
out = open("./pat.sec", "wb") # python   flush bug
out.close
os.system('sec2ts 0 < ./pat.sec > ./pat.ts')
os.remove('pat.sec')
```

... where PAT is the name of the table, sec2ts is a command from OpenCaster (software for muxing TS for digital television), and at the end I deleted the .sec file for it's no longer important.

Now, from a muxed .ts file I extracted one of the tables (PAT) in .sec format, and I need to return it back to .py so I can analyze its code, or watch the code used to define it in the first place.

My question is: how can I extract the code and save it in a .py file from a .sec file? Is there any kind of inverse process of what I did above?

Here's the rest of the .py  file, just in case:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os 

from dvbobjects.PSI.PAT import *
from dvbobjects.DVB.Descriptors import * 
from dvbobjects.MPEG.Descriptors import *

pat = program_association_section(
    table_id = 0,
    section_syntax_indicator = 1,
    current_next_indicator = 1,
    transport_stream_id = 22,
    version_number = 1,
    section_number = 0,
    last_section_number = 0,
    program_loop = [
        program_loop_item(
            program_number = 47,
            PID = 0x0010,
        ),
        program_loop_item(
            program_number = 49,
            PID = 0x0013,
        ),
        program_loop_item(
            program_number = 51,
            PID = 0x0014,
        ),
    ],
)

out = open("./pat.sec", "wb")
out.write(pat.pack())
out.close
out = open("./pat.sec", "wb") # python   flush bug
out.close
os.system('sec2ts 0 < ./pat.sec > ./pat.ts')
os.remove('pat.sec')
```

Comment: Could you expand on your question?

Comment: I just modified the post, adding the question itself.

Comment: Thank you for the update. My answer follows below.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your using opencaster to do the bulk of the conversion via system() calls.

From what I can tell opencaster does not have a way to do the inverse but there is a python project [telxcc](http://pythonhackers.com/p/petrkutalek/telxcc) which can extract [teletext](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teletext) from Transport Stream files.